# Macro to hide / unhide sheets based on button

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to have a button hide/unhide sheets when clicked.

The code I have will make a worksheet visible when the worksheet is hidden when button is given a ticked.  However, it will not make the worksheet invisible when it is unselected.

```
Sub CheckBox1_Click()

Dim i As Integer
    Sheets("A").Visible = True

End Sub
```

I would like the sheet to be invisible when unclicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Not` and the current `Visible` state to toggle:

```
Sub CheckBox1_Click()   
    Sheets("A").Visible = Not Sheets("A").Visible 
End Sub
```

If you specifically want to guarantee that *checked* = *visible* and *unchecked* = *hidden*, then use this:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    Sheets("A").Visible = CheckBox1.Value
End Sub
```